# How to display SQL bit variable as a string using ajax

Tags: javascript, sql, asp.net, ajax

I call C# function from js in ASP.NET. The problem is a SQL `bit` variable is displayed as "undefined" when retrieved in response. All other variables are retrieved successfully.

The SQL statement:

```
SELECT
    [UserID], [Name], [Badge], [Status],
    CASE WHEN [isAdmin] = 0 THEN 'No' 
         WHEN [isAdmin] = 1 THEN 'Yes'
    END AS [isAdmin]
FROM Admin
```

**js:**

```
function Retrieve() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "UsersList.aspx/Retrieve",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: successRetrieve,
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert("Error");
                }
            });
        }

function successRetrieve(response) {
            alert(response.d[i].IsAdmin); // "undefined"
             alert(response.d[i].Status); // "retrieved correctly"
              alert(response.d[i].Name); // "retrieved correctly"
}
```

C# web service:

```
while (dr.Read())
{
    ListOfUsersList.Add(
                 new User
                 {
                     UserID = dr["UserID"].ToString(),
                     Name = dr["Name"].ToString(),
                     Badge = dr["Badge"].ToString(),
                     Status = dr["Status"].ToString(),
                     isAdmin = dr["isAdmin"].ToString(), // "when I debug it is yes"
                 });
            }
```

`User` class:

```
public class User
{
    public string UserID;
    public string Name;
    public string Badge;
    public string Status;
    public string isAdmin;
}
```

Comment: Console the response!

Comment: And where is `i` declared?

Comment: which "i" do you mean?

Comment: Check case! `IsAdmin` and in the class `isAdmin`.

Comment: yes, that should be a mistake!

Comment: @VDWWD !!!! OMG!!! what a stupid mistake. i spent more than 1 day trying to solve this problem. thanks a lot.

Comment: @AlaaAlarfaj, no problem. I know how you feel. You have looked so much that you cannot see it anymore. Been there done that. A fresh pair of eyes can help.